# Add a 'New File' button similar to the 'New Folder Button' (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-explorer

[image]

I like how Windows 7 (and Vista) have the convenient 'New Folder' button. Is it possible to have a similar 'New File' button. If it creates a file and then automatically triggers the renaming action so you can rename the file, that would be perfect.

I know it is possible for certain file types to have special actions assigned, but not just for a generic directory.

Comment: But what file type? I get that you could determine that through renaming, but for *a lot* of file types: a file with zero data does not equate to an blank format

Comment: Windows files need some sort of extension, so it needs to be specified first, so this would be quite difficult. It would be easier with a unix based operating system which are not extension dependent

Comment: a completely 0-byte file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom buttons to Windows Explorer:

[Add a Custom Command Button to the Windows 7 Explorer Toolbar](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/A_2173-Add-a-Custom-Command-Button-to-the-Windows-7-Explorer-Toolbar.html)

See this article for the details, you need to add keys to the registry, and you'll need some sort of Command to actually do the work.

You might want something as simple as a batch file somewhere that just creates an empty file:

[newfile.bat]:

```
@ECHO OFF
COPY /Y null %1\new.txt
```

Would do, and would create an empty (zero-byte) file at the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps a bit ---> [Adding Toolbar Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(VS.85).aspx).